# LINKED Server does not return all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is a little strange for me. I have script like following

```
DECLARE @maxCustId INT
SELECT @maxCustId = MAX(CustomerId) FROM Customers
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM linkserver.DB.dbo.Customers where CustomerId > @maxCustId 

-- Copy records to local db Custome table

DROP TABLE #temp
```

But sometimes #temp does not fetch all records from linked sever.

Like I had `Max CustomerId = 1138` in my local db and when I run above script my temp table (which fetch records from linked server) misses `CustoemrIds 1140, 1141`. Linked server has `customers upto 1160`. `#temp` table has records `upto 1160` but misses two records i.e. `1140, 1141`

I run that script again and again and on 4th attempt the record `1141` added in #temp table but record `1140` was still missing.

I then put following query on local server to check record in linked server

```
SELECT * FROM linkserver.DB.dbo.Customers where CustomerId = 1140
```

Above query return no records.

To verify this I went to linked server and wrote same query on server from where I have created LINKED server.

```
-- This is the server which I am using as linked server in my local server
SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerId = 1140
```

`Custoemr 1140` was in db, which I was sure that it would be there but I run above script to verify it.

I come back to my local server and run this query

```
SELECT * FROM linkserver.DB.dbo.Customers where CustomerId = 1140
```

This time my linked server returns `customer 1140` which it was not returning earlier.

I run the whole query again and now my #temp table has all records.

I am so confused that why first time linked server did not return all records.

This is sample from a long procedure which copy records from linked server to local server and because of this reason my local db has less records than linked server db.

- **Linked server:** SQL Server 2005 Standard with SP2
- **Local Server:** SQL Server 2008 Web Edition with SP2
- **Provider:** SQL Native Client 10

Linked server security options:

- Be made using the securing context
- Remote Login
- With Passowrd

login user details:

- Server Roles: public and sysadmin
- User Mappings: sa is not mapped with
  db I query.
- Linked server db updated frequently
- No NOLOCK at any point in query

Any help.

Comment: You are selecting into #temp from table swyx.Atia.dbo.Ippbxcdr, yet you are trying to verify the existence of a record in linkserver.DB.dbo.Customers. What about when you run the query on the database server that contains Atia.dbo.Ippbxcdr?

Comment: I have edited my question and the record which missed in #temp table exists in linkserver.db.dbo.Customers

Comment: Can you just SELECT * FROM linkserver.DB.dbo.Customers with no WHERE clause and see if the missing rows show up?

Comment: I've had some pretty odd results with a linked Oracle server along these lines. Out of interest, what happens if you `SELECT CustomerId FROM linkserver.DB.dbo.Customers where CustomerId = 1140` instead of `SELECT * ...`?

Comment: @Matt, as I wrote that linked server miss records sometimes so I am trying to reproduce this again to answer @HardCode question of not using WHERE clause and will answer your question of using CustomerId instead of fetching all columns.

Comment: Looks like you have linked to another server, which slowly reflects (replicates) first server data or so :)

Comment: @Arvo thanks for your response. Can you please explain what do you mean by linked to another server? Of course I am linked to another server, that is what linked server is. OR I am not getting you?

Comment: I meant your linked server (which didn't return 1140) is not the same where you locally queried and got 1140. Like when you have dev, test1, test2 and prod server (or instances) and you think that your linked server is connected to test1, but in reality it is connected to test2 (or prod :)) Sure that scenario is not likely, but is possible.

Comment: @Arvo, it is same server. Both servers are productions server the one which has linked server and the one which is linked server. No test server or any other server is involved in this scenario except these 2 servers. this explains your question? OR should I edit my question to make it more clear?

Comment: Is it possible the primary server has long-running transactions that are tied to the "missing" records?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar behaviour with linked servers (although usually Oracle not SQL Server) and the problem was traced to the driver being used for the linked server. 
I see you have SQL Native Client 10 as the provider, could you try using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server instead and seeing if it makes a difference?

Answer (score -1):

Also would be curious to know if you have the same problem when you use OpenQuery instead of the four-part naming convention:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(linkserver,'SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerId = 1140')
```

IIRC, that should be faster, anyway... I believe that would force it to take care of the "where" part on the linked server and only return the appropriate values as opposed to returning the whole dataset and doing the filterin' on the destination side.  Of course, I'm also pretty sure I saw a UFO at my Granny's house when I was eight, so take my wisdom with a grain of salt.

Comment: Ok let me change my query using OPENQUERY and test it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OPENQUERY is also not working. Same problem of missing few records.